# Java + Regex: matching characters from a customized set that are not preceded by characters in the same set

Tags: java, regex

I am running into a silly problem with Regular Expressions in Java where I would like to match a String that begins with @ with characters from a certain valid set, but are not preceded by characters from the same valid set.

The terms I would like to match are of the form:

"y" + @ + "xxxxxxx"

where:

- x is a character that belongs to the valid set `[a-zA-Z\\d\\-\\_]`
- the @ sign appears once
- y is a character that does **not** belong to the valid set `[a-zA-Z\\d\\-\\_]`

I'm currently trying to do this this by using the following regular expressions pattern

```
MY_PATTERN = "[^[A-Za-z\\d\\-\\_]?]" + "@{1}" + "[A-Za-z\\d\\-\\_]+"
String text = "12a@cat123-_     @dog123__- ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
```

Based on this I expect the following code to only print `@dog123__-`

`while(m.find()){
   String s = m.group();
   System.out.println(s);
}`

However it also prints out `a@cat123-_`.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it should be [^A-Za-z\\d\\-\\_] instead of ^[A-Za-z\\d\\-\\_] if you mean "not in the set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the text you're trying to match could be anywhere, and not anchored to the start of the string.

The syntax you used for `[^[A-Za-z\\d\\-\\_]?]` is wrong and is being interpreted as something else (let's not get into that). Negated character classes are `[^chars]`. So the syntax should have been `[^A-Za-z\\d\\-_]`. However, that *requires* to match that character before the `"@"`, so it won't match `"@foo"`, because "there isn't a character (that is not A-Za-z0-9-_) before".

[Lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.htm) to the rescue. A negative lookbehind `(?<!subpattern)` specifies the current position is not preceded by subpattern.

Oh, and one more thing, `[A-Za-z\\d\\-_]` is the same as `[-\\w]` (let's use that shorter version).

So the regex should be:

```
(?<![-\\w])@[-\\w]+
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/YySaxt)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues in your pattern, here's one that should do it:

```
(?:^|[^A-Za-z\d\-\_])(@[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+)
```

1. `@{1}` it's the same as `@`
2. `[^[A-Za-z\d\-\_]?]` The problem seems to be here, you're using nested character sets, which doesn't work
3. It should be `[^A-Za-z\d\-\_]`

You could simplify the regex to: `(?:^|[^\w\-])(@[\w\-]+)`

`\w` matches any alphanumeric character & underscore

Test this: http://regexr.com/3bt77

It's javascript, but you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  Out of curiosity, what do the parentheses do here?

Comment: The parentheses create a capture group, so you just output exactly what you want, having this regex /[a-z]([0-9]+)/  and this string "a999" The captured group will be "999"

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande that regex **requires** a character before the `@`.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just corrected the syntax of the OP to make it work with his regex. Anyway in javascript you can't use lookbehinds (I know is a java question) so I couldn't test it. Your's should be the accepted answer. Anyway that's why I added the capture group.

Comment: Just pointing out a probably undesired result. In JavaScript, this could be solved as `/(?:^|[^-\w])(@[-\w]+)/g`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be simplified considerably, given:

```
[a-zA-Z\\d\\-\\_] === [\w-]
```

so this is what what you want:

```
[^\w-]@[\w-]
```